# Tetgen: starting from given triangles of a surface, create a new mesh without change the connectivity of the surface

Tags: c++, mesh, tetgen

I am using tetgen, but I am having troubles. I want to create a mesh, starting from given triangles of a surface. I do not want to change the given triangles.
In particular, I am working on a domain such that: there is an external cubic box with an internal hole (a box too). The triangles I have are the ones of the internal and external surfaces. I want to build the mesh between the two surfaces. Unforunately, I am not succeeding.

The input I use is of this type:

- number of nodes, 3, 0, 1  (no regions, but markers)

-lists of nodes

- number of facets, 1 (markers)

-lists of facets

- 1 (1 hole)

-coordinates of the hole

- 0 (no region)

The list of facets is the list of triangles of both surfaces, internal and external. I have considered the most simple mesh for this kind of domain. And I am sure the input I give to tetgen is "right".I have displayed it on matlab and it coincides with the one i desire. Probably what i desire is not what tetgen wants... 
Nevertheless tetgen finds intersecting triangles that are not intersecting. They share a side, but i think facets can share sides! Or Am I wrong? Or maybe is the fact that some triangles are coplanar? 
I think there is something wrong in my input, conceptually speaking, but I do not understand what.

When i call tetgen I use the "-Y" switch in order to avoid changements in the surface. I have tried both the -p and the -q switches, separetly or togheter. But always the same error occurs.
Can somebody help me, please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

since your input geometry is so simple, just two nested cubes, I believe this should not be a problem of tetgen.
To make sure that your input is correct, try the -d option of tetgen first.
Another way is to use other tools to create your input for tetgen, such as Gmsh.